# Foundation, How to set an button like onclick?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I use foundation in my rails application, now i would like to style an normal button:

```
  <a href="#" class="button">Default Button</a>
```

Like when it was clicked! The problem is i dont find any class like "active" for example or "hover" in the foundation code.

Answer (score 0):

There should be styling for :hover in the foundation.css file - about half way around the 1300 line mark.

```
  button:hover, button:focus, .button:hover, .button:focus {
    background-color: #1968e7; }
  button:hover, button:focus, .button:hover, .button:focus {
    color: white; }
```

you could add an :active selector there if you would like or in your own stylesheet as there are not :active states in the foundation styles.